# Node js and mongodb cannot connect docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

Both these services work individually, Yet when I go to the docker endpoint through the container the app crashes as it fails to connect to my database. Can anyone see why?

After running docker-compose i have inspected each container individually and they work fine but just not together. Unsure as to why as for others it seems to work

Docker compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo
    # volumes:
    #   - ./db:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  # frontend:
  #   build:
  #     context: './frontend/'
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #   container_name: reactfront
  #   # depends_on: [server]
  #   ports:
  #     - '3000:3000'
  #   restart: always
  server:
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nodeserver
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    restart: always
    depends_on: [db]
    links:
      - db
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Node js app

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000
var cors = require('cors')
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
app.use(cors())
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Worldd!')
})
app.get('/docker', async (req, res) => {
  let myres;
  client.connect().then(async (db, b) => {
    myres = await db.db().admin().listDatabases()
    console.log(await db.db().admin().listDatabases());
    res.json(myres)
  })
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker-compose will create a bridge network and the containers will be able to resolve each others' names.

Replace
`const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'` with `const uri = 'mongodb://db:27017'` (db is mongo's service name).

Comment: that works thank you. Can i ask where you found this info? Every tutorial I have seen doesn't require this... I also didn't require this when it was just a node API and a front end...

Comment: I highly recommand checking the docker networking docs https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: It doesnt mention anything in your answer?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/   " ... Within the web container, your connection string to db would look like postgres://db:5432, and from the host machine ..."

Answer (score 0):

You cant use localhost apparently as they are in different containers (seems obvious now) - I checked the IP of the container and put that into the mongo url